# Observations get in a line in a PCA score plot. Something wrong with the data?

Tags: clustering, pca

I ran a clustering and in the resultant PCA score plot some observations getting in a line drew my attention (I marked them with a red line) . How come they distribute like that? I doubt there is something wrong with the data. What can I do with the data?
[image]

Comment: It looks as if your data were right-censored. Clustering has nothing to to with it. [This question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33165/3277), thought not exactly same, was instructive.

Comment: Any chance these are **0 values in one of the attributes**? Without PCA, it would probably be easier to interpret.

Comment: There is no 0 value in the attributes.