# Does SPSS Homoscedasticity Residual scatterplot have meaning for Likert Data?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss

I'd think using plots to test the assumptions of multiple linear regression requires some experience anyway, but in this case all my independent variables, and my dependent variable,  are 5-level Likert rather than continuous variables.

I understand applying non-ordinal regression to this kind of data is somewhat controversial, but is often done.

The plot consists of 5 linear arrays of points at 45 degrees. Is that interpretable at all?

If not, what should be substituted?

Comment: Yes,thanks and sorry. That post IS a duplicate, covering the same ground, and as suspected the pattern IS apparently due to non-continuous data,

Comment: Hi, here is even a more upvoted thread about the same "straight lines" phenomenon https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33165/3277

Comment: Visit this too https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/287669/3277

Comment: Ed, if you think it is a duplicate and your question isn't going to be informative, then you could ask a moderator to close or delete it.